# DRY Strategy for looping over unknown levels of nested objects

Tags: ruby

My scenario is based on Gmail API.

I've learned that email messages can have their message parts deeply or shallowly nested based upon varying factors, but mostly the presence of attachments.

I'm using the [Google API Ruby Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-ruby-client) gem, so I'm not working with JSON, I'm getting objects with all the same information, but I think the JSON representation makes it easier to understand my issue.

A simple message JSON response looks like this (one `parts` array with 2 hashes inside it):

```
{
  "id": "175b418b1ff69896",
  "snippet": "COVID-19: Resources to help your business manage through uncertainty 20 Liters 500 PEOPLE FOUND YOU ON GOOGLE Here are the top search queries used to find you: 20 liters used by 146 people volunteer",
  "payload": {
    "parts": [
      {
        "mimeType": "text/plain",
        "body": {
          "data": "Hey, you found the body of the email! I want this!"
        }
      },
      {
        "mimeType": "text/html",
        "body": {
          "data": "<div>I actually don't want this</div>"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The value I want is not that hard to get:

```
response.payload.parts.each do |part|
  @body_data = part.body.data if part.mime_type == 'text/plain'
end
```

BUT The JSON response of a more complex email message with attachments looks something like this (now `parts` nests itself 3 levels deep):

```
{
  "id": "175aee26de8209d2",
  "snippet": "snippet text...",
  "payload": {
    "parts": [
      {
        "mimeType": "multipart/related",
        "parts": [
          {
            "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
            "parts": [
              {
                "mimeType": "text/plain",
                "body": {
                  "data": "hey, you found me! This is what I want!!"
                }
              },
              {
                "mimeType": "text/html",
                "body": {
                  "data": "<div>I actually don't want this one.</div>"
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
          },
          {
            "mimeType": "image/png"
          },
          {
            "mimeType": "image/png"
          },
          {
            "mimeType": "image/jpeg"
          },
          {
            "mimeType": "image/png"
          },
          {
            "mimeType": "image/png"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "mimeType": "application/pdf"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And looking at a few other messages, the object can vary from 1 to 5 levels (maybe more) of `parts`

I need to loop over an unknown number of parts and then loop over an unknown number of nested parts and the repeat this again until I reach the bottom, hopefully finding the thing I want.

Here's my best attempt:

```
def trim_response(response)
  # remove headers I don't care about
  response.payload.headers.keep_if { |header| @valuable_headers.include? header.name }

  # remove parts I don't care about
  response.payload.parts.each do |part|
    # parts can be nested within parts, within parts, within...
    if part.mime_type == @valuable_mime_part && part.body.present?
      @body_data = part.body.data
      break
    elsif part.parts.present?
      # there are more layers down
      find_body(part)
    end
  end
end

def find_body(part)
  part.parts.each do |sub_part|
    if sub_part.mime_type == @valuable_mime_part && sub_part.body.present?
      @body_data = sub_part.body.data
      break
    elsif sub_part.parts.present?
      # there are more layers down
      ######### THIS FEELS BAD!!! ###########
      find_body(sub_part)
    end
  end
end
```

Yep, there's a method calling itself. I know, that's why I'm here.

This does work, I've tested it on a few dozen messages, but... there has to be a better, DRY-er way to do this.

#### How do I recursively loop and then move down a level and loop again in a DRY fashion when I don't know how deep the nesting goes?

Comment: You just want first body value ?

Comment: Nothing is particularly bad with the recursive solution, I'd go with it. In fact, recursion usually is _the cleanest_ way to solve this class of tasks. Sure, you always have a chance of things getting out of control but do you really think in this case - Gmail API - the nesting can really go _that_ deep? You could replace the recursion with a stack-baked iterative traversal, but it doesn't solve the memory issue - if your nesting level is unlimited you will get out of memory sooner or later. Tracking the depth and raising an error if it's too deep already might help...

Comment: @ZainArshad, I want the `body.data` where the `mime_type` is 'text/plain'

Comment: @Chiperific By seeing the pattern the first part with body in it will surely be the part having mime_type as "text/plain"

Comment: @Chiperific You can run my code on various responses and let me know if it is working fine, It will be

Comment: @ZainArshad I'm not guaranteed to have the 'text/plain' as the first terminating branch. Some email services send the 'text/html' before the 'text/plain'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go through all this pain. Just keep diving in the `parts` dictionary until you find the first value where there is no `parts` anymore. At this moment you have the final `parts` in your `parts` variable.

**Code:**

```
reponse = {"id" => "175aee26de8209d2","snippet" => "snippet text...","payload" => {"parts" => [{"mimeType" => "multipart/related","parts" => [{"mimeType" => "multipart/alternative","parts" => [{"mimeType" => "text/plain","body" => {"data" => "hey, you found me! This is what I want!!"}},{"mimeType" => "text/html","body" => {"data" => "<div>I actually don't want this one.</div>"}}]},{"mimeType" => "image/jpeg"}]},{"mimeType" => "application/pdf"}]}}
parts   = reponse["payload"]
parts   = (parts["parts"].send("first") || parts["parts"]) while parts["parts"]
data    = parts["body"]["data"]
puts data
```

**Output:**

```
hey, you found me! This is what I want!!
```

Comment: This only works when the data is in the first branch of the tree. I need to be able to match `mime_type` to make sure I'm getting the 'text/plain' data.

Comment: I think you have the idea how to solve this issue, now its a great time to figure out how to add the final check

Comment: I like the track you're headed down, but I'd need to implement 2 more things: 1.) checking the `mime_type` on the `parts` object and 2.) popping out the `parts` as I reject them so I can continue to call `first` on the object's parts. I've been playing with this and it's not much more readable nor is it more memory efficient as I'm still iterating over everything. Gonna give you credit since I asked for a DRY-er way and you gave it.

Comment: this is efficient you need to iterate over each hash until you find the correct body tag, there is no way other than checking each key

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the desired result using recursion.

```
def find_it(h, top_key, k1, k2, k3)
  return nil unless h.key?(top_key)
  recurse(h[top_key], k1, k2, k3)
end
```

```
def recurse(h, k1, k2, k3)
  return nil unless h.key?(k1)      
  h[k1].each do |g|
    v = g.dig(k2,k3) || recurse(g, k1 , k2, k3)
    return v unless v.nil?
  end
  nil
end
```

See [Hash#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig).

Let `h1` and `h2` equal the two hashes given in the example<sup>1</sup>. Then:

```
find_it(h1, :payload, :parts, :body, :data)
  #=> "Hey, you found the body of the email! I want this!"
```

```
find_it(h2, :payload, :parts, :body, :data)
  #=> "hey, you found me! This is what I want!!"
```

<sup>1. The hash `h[:payload][:parts].last #=> { "mimeType": "application/pdf" }` appears to contain hidden characters that are causing a problem. I therefore removed that hash from `h2`.</sup>